get stuck in line 1-8/8 (END), what to type next?
I am at this step
Step 5. Install PostgreSQL
type sudo apt-get install postgresql -y
sudo systemctl start postgresql && sudo systemctl enable postgresql

Synchronizing state of postgresql.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable postgresql

sudo systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2024-04-24 03:56:27 +08; 27min ago
   Main PID: 1289 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms

Apr 24 03:56:27 janice-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EAN-K513EA systemd[1]: Starting >
Apr 24 03:56:27 janice-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EAN-K513EA systemd[1]: Finished >
...skipping...
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2024-04-24 03:56:27 +08; 27min ago
   Main PID: 1289 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms

Apr 24 03:56:27 janice-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EAN-K513EA systemd[1]: Starting >
Apr 24 03:56:27 janice-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EAN-K513EA systemd[1]: Finished >
~
~
line 1-8/8 (END)

I get stuck here, unable to continue, unable to type command useradd -m -U -r -d /opt/odoo17 -s /bin/bash odoo17
any idea how to proceed to the next step?
